# splitting a single value

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
<td data-X="1,2">
```

and when I do:

```
var Y = $('td').data('X');
Z=Y.split();
```

it works.

But if I have:

```
<td data-X="1">
```

then it doesn't work.
At least I think that's what's happening.  I'm getting "Y.split is not a function", but only sometimes.

Comment: You probably also want to be splitting the comma: `Y.split(",");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.data()` is smart. It tries to use a more appropriate type than `string` for the value - in your case, it's `number`.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/data):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the attr() method.

Comment: thanks for the link.  I tried it with attr and had the same results.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if it's being interpreted as an integer instead of a string. Try `Z = Y.toString( ).split( )`